# How to remove "Set Image as Desktop Background" and other annoying options from Firefox context menu?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, context-menu, css

I just want to get rid of some Firefox context menu, such as:
"set as desktop background"
"email image"
"bookmark link"

Now in Firefox, addons cannot change context menu.
I have tried to add

```
#context-setDesktopBackground {display:none!important}
```

to the `userChrome.css` file, but it also not working. Is there any solution?

UPDATE
I have tried also

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */

#context-setDesktopBackground {display:none!important}
```

And also not working:

[image]

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/stonecrusher/simpleMenuWizard/tree/master#instructions).

Comment: Did you follow discussion at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1292122 ?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik yes, and it is not working. Or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You should link to the GH repository if that's what you're using, as of now your question is completely out of context.

Comment: Does [this solution](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1116486) still work ?

Comment: @harrymc it is the same as suggested DrMoishePippik and now it is not working...

Comment: @Destroy666 Am am using an official Firefox release... And I want to change exactly firefox context menu.

Comment: @Destroy666 I am using windows 10 x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested and the GitHub solution still works fine in latest Firefox. You likely failed to follow instructions in a way or another - please specify what you tried exactly in your question next time.

Here very simplified instructions for Windows 10 (based on [this repo](https://github.com/stonecrusher/simpleMenuWizard#instructions)):

1. Open `about:config` page in Firefox and search for `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets`. Set it to `true` if it's `false` by e.g. double clicking the value.
2. Create `userChrome.css` file in `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[profile-id]\chrome`:

- `%APPDATA%` is `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming`
- `profile-id` dir should be the one with latest date modified, if you used Firefox recently
- `chrome` dir at the end might not exist, you need to create that too then

3. Add this to that file:

```css
#context-sep-setbackground, #context-setDesktopBackground, #context-setDesktopBackground { display:none !important; }
```

This removes the **Set Image as Desktop Background...** entry and separators, as an example. Selectors are taken from [here](https://github.com/stonecrusher/simpleMenuWizard/blob/master/simpleMenuWizard/image-context.css), you can check for other ones in [other files](https://github.com/stonecrusher/simpleMenuWizard/tree/master/simpleMenuWizard), for each type of context menu.

4. Save the file and (re)open Firefox. Menu entry should be gone.

Comment: Thank you! 'toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets' - "legacy" means that it will not work after some time?

Comment: No problem. It is possible that it will get removed, but "legacy" itself doesn't necessarily mean it will be soon. Quick google for "`toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` deprecated" shows no interesting results, so if it's not deprecated then it's unlikely to disappear suddenly. And it is called that since 2019 BTW.