# Customize "file not found" page in Firefox 114

Tags: firefox, webpage

How do I customize the file not found page in Firefox 114? I have tried the methods I can find by searching, but can't get any of them to work.

I'm trying to customize or ideally replace the error page for `file://` files. I doesn't have to be just for `file://` protocol. this is for an offline personal project that is not using a server.

I have tried:

- Setting `browser.xul.error_pages.enabled` to `true`
- Setting `browser.xul.error_pages.404` to a path containing my `404.html`:

```
<html> <head> </head> <body> <p>This is my error page</p> </body> </html>
```

- Adding a `certerror.xhtml` page to `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\content\browser\`. I didn't think this would work, but it was worth a try.
- Editing the `user.js` file to include:

```
user_pref("browser.xul.error_pages.enabled", true);
user_pref("browser.xul.error_pages.404", "file:///C:/Users/Greg/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/o1e6yv2w.default-release/errorpages/404.html");
```

Still no luck.

Comment: Hello, what exactly did you try? People usually want to know so that they avoid giving you the same advice, you know. And customize how? Also, why just for `file://` protocol? I doubt that's possible.

Comment: @Destroy666 I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: I still don't see what exactly you're attempting to customize.

Comment: I want to a be able to change the html for the page, add some javascript and change the css.

Comment: Ok, but please show some examples of what you're trying to do. We can't possibly know if your HTML/CSS/JS is any valid.

Comment: At the moment I am just trying to get a basic html file to work.
Once I can get that to work I know I can get the rest to work.
`<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is my error page</p>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you got `browser.xul.error_pages.404` from, but this question is the only reference to it on the internet. `certerror.xhtml` doesn't sound like anything related to 404 page either.

To find the actual file to edit, you can:

- go to `%ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox` (usually `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox`)
- open `omni.ja` archive with e.g. 7-zip
- go to `chrome\toolkit\content\global` and open `aboutNetError.xhtml`

If you check the HTML source, it'll match the source of the 404 page for missing file.

The problem is that the archive is signed and the contents are verified for each version, so you won't be able to edit it. I also don't think there's another way to edit the file, that wouldn't be great in terms of security, if a virus could let's say inject some crypto miner to all your 404 pages.

You can, however, change the CSS at the very least. Check [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1785228/1145698) to learn about the basics of editing `userChrome.css`. E.g. `.neterror .title-text` would let you edit the error title.

Comment: `browser.xul.error_pages.404` is in `about:config`
The `certerror.xhtml` was suggested by AI. I was curious and tried it before I asked the question here.

I also tried renaming `omni.js` to `omni.zip` editing the file and renaming it to `omni.ja`, but as you said it didn't work. It might be time to give up.

Comment: It's there because you added it, I don't have anything like that on an almost fresh install. Or maybe it's some leftover for you from older version.

Comment: Sorry, you're probably right. I've been mucking around so much I'm starting to forget what I've changed. I think I'll refresh Firefox and not worry about trying to edit it.
Thank you very much for your time.