# How to disable (or at least close) "You are sharing another application window" floating bar?

Tags: firefox, screen-sharing

In Firefox, when I'm on Google Chat or Jitsi and share my screen, Firefox shows me this annoying floating bar containing:

> You are sharing another application window

I can minimize but not close it. How do I permanently disable this message/window? And if that's not possible, is it possible to even close it?

Google Chat:

[image: Bar in Google chat]

Jitsi:

[image: Bar in Jitsi]

Comment: @Ramhound: Because I get the exact same message whether in Google Chat or Jitsi

Comment: It still does not not prove that it is Firefox.

Comment: @RohitGupta: See Destroy666's answer

Comment: @Ramhound: See Destroy666's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That popup is defined as [`webrtcIndicator.xhtml`](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/webrtcIndicator.xhtml).

You can disable it through `userChrome.css` editing. A styling like this one should work:

```
@-moz-document url('chrome://browser/content/webrtcIndicator.xhtml') {
  :root {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

`:root` matches the entire document, so basically the `<html>` tag and then you hide it with classic [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) change.

Check [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1785228/1145698) for details about the `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[profile-id]\chrome\userChrome.css` file and how to make it editable in current Firefox version, assuming your system is Windows.

Comment: [1/2] To make it easier for dummies like me, here's what I did and worked: **1.** Open `about:config` page in Firefox and search for `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets`. Set it to `true` if it's `false`. **2.** Go to `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles` where `XXX` is replaced by your Windows user name. **3.** If there are more than one folder there, go into the folder that has many more files & folders (in my case it was `8tyvfse3.default-release`). **4.** In `8tyvfse3.default-release` (or similar folder), create folder `chrome`.

Comment: [2/2] **5.** Download this file [`userChrome.css`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bs_Sj-H4bd3O9Fy6emtImqc8RAzafZc4) and paste it in the `chrome` folder you just created. **6.** Restart Firefox and now it should work.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what the linked answer says, thanks for summarizing here though. I don't bother copy pasting it to all `userChrome` answers as it's a rather long list of instructions and the repetition is not worth IMO, unless that question author deletes it for some reason, but then there's even [whole website](https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html) dedicated to the file. And if the method changes I can just update one answer.